# codeigniter ajax not working.Tried whatever I could

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

I have the ajax function

```
$('a[name=deleteButton]').on('click', function () {
    arr=[];
    var arr = $("input[name='post[]']:checked").map(function() { 
            return this.value; 
          }).get();
          var content = $(this).parents('tr').find('.key').html();
          alert(content);
});

function makeAjaxCall(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "http://localhost/partner/app/UserController/verifyUser",
        cache: false,               
        data: {id : content},
        success: function(data){                        
                alert('hi');
        },
        error: function(td){                        
            alert(td.responseText);
        }
 });
}
```

The controller is

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class UserController extends CI_Controller {

    public function verifyUser()    {

        $status = array("STATUS"=>"false");

        echo json_encode ($status) ;    
    }
}
```

The view is

```
<tr>
                                <td><input type='checkbox' name='post[]' value="<?php echo ++$i; ?>"></td>
                                <td><?php echo date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['connct_CreationTime']));?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['connct_serviceName'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['connct_websiteUrl'];?></td>
                                <td class="key"><?php echo $row['connct_passKey'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['responseURL'];?></td>
                                <td><a name="deleteButton"  href=""><i class="icon-remove text-danger"></i></a></td>
                                <!-- <td align='center' width='30'><a data-toggle='modal' href='#' ><i class='icon-remove text-danger'></i></a></td> -->
                            </tr>
```

var content is getting alerted.But in the network tab , its showing ajax POST is cancelled.
Why this is not working.Also the error,td.responseText is blank
I have tried all I could , but its not working.Please help me find a solution

Comment: Is csrf_protection is enabled ????

Comment: @rajeshkakawat What is it?

Comment: check this out http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/security.html

Comment: @rajeshkakawat I turned On.let me test.But what it has to do with this?

Comment: I want to know if its is ON or OFF.

Comment: from where makeAjaxCall() function is called????

Comment: Is your content global variable

Comment: How to make it global variable?

Comment: @rajeshkakawat Please check the code carefully $('a[name=deleteButton]').on('click', function ()  This calls javascript

Comment: but delete button click function is not calling makeAjaxCall() function

Answer (score 0):

**Possible solution**

`http://localhost/partner/app/UserController/verifyUser` use this url directly in browser to check if url is correct or not and also check what output is coming?

if your desired output is coming or not

**EIDTED**

From my point of view your code should be like this

```
    $('a[name=deleteButton]').on('click', function () {
        arr=[];
        var arr = $("input[name='post[]']:checked").map(function() { 
                return this.value; 
              }).get();
              var content = $(this).parents('tr').find('.key').html();
              makeAjaxCall(content);
             return false;
    });

    function makeAjaxCall(content){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "http://localhost/partner/app/UserController/verifyUser",
            cache: false,               
            data: {id : content},
            success: function(data){                        
                    alert('hi');
            },
            error: function(td){                        
                alert(td.responseText);
            }
     });
    }
```

Comment: Yes the output is coming when i goto this URL.

Comment: Im getting blank alerts yyaar :(

Comment: Im trying your code..You are right i wasnt calling ajax function,sorry i missed that part in the question sorry

Comment: Btw Im getting two alerts when i used ur code..Both are blank alerts

Comment: Im getting content as 'Hghh766' which is the value of the variable content when i alerted it

Comment: Im trying this for the past two days,and i cant get this working buddy :(

Comment: got it just return false from your button function check edited code

Comment: Thank you for testing this at ur side.But I dont know I cant get it working.I dont know why.Will it be a browser issue?

Comment: This is status which comes in the network tab "failed)
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"